# Is there a way to keep IE dialog boxes from locking the IE window behind other windows?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've noticed this annoying behavior since at least IE8.  The issue is that when IE opens a modal dialog box (eg, Javascript alert, script error dialog, etc) and the IE window gets pushed behind other windows on the desktop before the dialog box is closed, you can't bring the IE window to the foreground by clicking on it.  The only way to get it to the foreground is to either 1) minimize all other windows in front of it or 2) click on the dialog box if it happens to be peeking out from behind other windows.

Open up this fiddle in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/kDkFd/

When the dialog opens, put any other window partially over the fiddle window, but make sure the dialog box is hidden.  You will notice that clicking the fiddle window does nothing unless you move the top window out of the way.  Now hide the fiddle window again, but this time leave a little piece of the dialog peeking out from the top window.  Clicking the dialog successfully brings the fiddle window to the foreground.

Is there some kind of patch/fix that addresses this annoying IE issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you'll find this to be an acceptable workaround, but when trying this on Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 9, clicking the IE icon in the taskbar (or if multiple windows are open, the menu item for the correct window in the popup menu) seems to bring both the main IE window and the dialog to the top.

I cannot reproduce the bug at all on my Windows XP machine running IE 8.

Comment: I just tested with IE 11 on Win 8.1 and could not reproduce the described issue. Just curious are you running an anti-virus product other than defender? If so try disabling it and trying again. The reason I ask is I know Anti-Virus products really screw up IE and cause all sorts of crazy behavior.